# How can I use a geom_point shape in an axis label or legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am comparing two variables (V1, V2) across subjects in three experimental conditions (C1, C2, C3). To that end, I have plotted distinct variable scores overlaid with estimated means ± credible intervals for each variable and condition.

[image: Example: Mean Comparison between Groups with Credible Intervals]

I am looking for a way to include the diamond symbol in the axis label or legend to identify it as the estimated mean. Will I have to rely on post-processing (e.g. in *Inkscape*) or is there a way to code this in *ggplot2*?

Below, I have copied a (simplified) *R* code for the estimated part of the plot. I would be very grateful for any advice!

```
  Condition <- c("C1", "C2", "C3", "C1", "C2", "C3")
  Variable  <- c("V1", "V1", "V1", "V2", "V2", "V2") 
  Estimate  <- c(3.05, 3.06, 3.21, 3.15, 3.14, 3.29)
  l95CI     <- c(2.81, 2.80, 2.97, 2.90, 2.88, 3.05)
  u95CI     <- c(3.30, 3.30, 3.46, 3.40, 3.39, 3.54)

  D <- data.frame(Condition, Variable, Estimate, l95CI, u95CI)

  F <- ggplot(D, aes(Condition, Estimate)) +
       geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = l95CI, ymax = u95CI), width = .2) +
       geom_point(fill = "white", shape = 23, size = 4) +
       ylim(1, 5) +
       labs(x = "Condition", y = "Score") + 
       facet_grid(. ~ Variable) +
       theme_bw()
```

EDIT: I have post-processed the original figure to include an additional legend for the estimated mean and credible interval as an example of how I would like the final plot to look like. I am still looking for a way to implement this (or a similar change to the axis label) in *ggplot2*.

[image: Modified example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't completely solve your issue, as I don't think the errorbar is a shape that you can specify. But generally speaking, you can set up custom legends using the `guides` function.

```
D <- data.frame(Condition, Variable, Estimate, l95CI, u95CI, type=factor(c("Estimated Mean  ", "95% CI  "), levels=c("Estimated Mean  ", "95% CI  ")))


ggplot(D, aes(x=Condition, y=Estimate, group=type, color=type)) +
       geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = l95CI, ymax = u95CI), width = .2) +
       geom_point(fill = "white", shape = 23, size = 4) +
       ylim(1, 5) +
       labs(x = "Condition", y = "Score") + 
       facet_grid(. ~ Variable) + 
       guides(col=guide_legend(title=NULL, override.aes=list(shape=c(23,124)), 
         keywidth=1.2)) + theme_bw() + theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.key=
         element_rect(size=5,color="white")) + 
         scale_color_manual(values=c("black", "black"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much for the help - I wasn't at all aware of the `guides` function. I have implemented fanli's advice and came up with this plot:

[image: Solution with new legend]

First, I added colour legends to the relevant `geom` elements.

```
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = l95CI, ymax = u95CI, colour = "95% CI"), width = .2) +
geom_point(aes(colour = "Estimated Mean"), fill = "white", shape = 23, size = 4)
```

Second, I specified the colours as black and reordered the labels.

```
scale_colour_manual(values = c('Estimated Mean' = 'black', '95% CI' = 'black'), limits = c('Estimated Mean', '95% CI'))
```

Third, I adjusted the shapes displayed in the legend to mirror the elements they are meant to reflect.

```
guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = c(23, 124), linetype = c(0, 0), size = c(4, 5))))
```

Finally, I moved the legend to the bottom of the plot.

```
theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
      legend.position = "bottom",
      legend.box = "horizontal"),
      legend.key = element_rect(colour = NA, fill = "white"))
```

The errorbar is still not perfectly replicated in the legend but I don't think it detracts from the clarity of the plot.